# WordPress: role update/change trigger

Tags: php, wordpress, time, triggers, roles

How can I get Date(Time) when user role last updated/changed ?

Can't find such trigger in WP, which helps me to get time of update.
I'm going to get right time like:

```
  $t=time('HH:mm:ss');
  echo gmdate("H:i:s", $t);
  echo '<p>time = '. date("Y-m-d H:m:s",$t) .'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the time of last update, you need the_modified_time function:

```
<?php the_modified_time('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_modified_time('g:i a'); ?>
```

[See wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_time)

Comment: Yep, it's showing time when POST modified, i need something else. I need to found time, when user role has changed/updated. I think it's going to place some timer in user-edit.php . But thanks!!